# How can I resolve an Error 404 issue in ct-ng build?

Tags: opensuse

I got crosstool-ng for openSuSE 42.2 via YaST (version 1.21.0-4.22). Installing crosstool itself did work fine, but when trying to build the crosscompiler with `ct-ng build`, I get the following error message:

```
[ALL  ]    --2018-02-01 21:36:27--  https://cbuild.validation.linaro.org/snapshots/binutils-linaro-2.25.0-2015.01-2
[ALL  ]    Connecting to cbuild.validation.linaro.org (cbuild.validation.linaro.org)|51.148.40.7|:443... connected.
[ALL  ]    HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
[ALL  ]    2018-02-01 21:36:27 ERROR 404: Not Found.
[ALL  ]    
[DEBUG]    Not at this location: "http://cbuild.validation.linaro.org/snapshots/binutils-linaro-2.25.0-2015.01-2"
[ERROR]  
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Build failed in step 'Retrieving needed toolchain components' tarballs'
[ERROR]  >>        called in step '(top-level)'
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  Error happened in: do_binutils_get[scripts/build/binutils/binutils.sh@741]
[ERROR]  >>        called from: main[scripts/crosstool-NG.sh@584]
[ERROR]  >>
[ERROR]  >>  For more info on this error, look at the file: 'build.log'
[ERROR]  >>  There is a list of known issues, some with workarounds, in:
[ERROR]  >>      '/usr/share/doc/packages/crosstool-ng/ct-ng.1.21.0/B - Known issues.txt'
```

The problem is: I can't influence the contents of Linaro's web servers. So is there a workaround to circumvent this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You use ct-ng 1.21 and that is very old (25 May 2015) and links can break.

I cross compile a lot with ct-ng and build lots of x-libs. But I build ct-ng from the sources. And I don't use HEAD or MASTER. I try instead the newest tag and if it fails I choose an older one and so on until I find a working tag. The current that works for me is "tags/crosstool-ng-1.23.0".

```
mkdir -p $HOME/_dev/_build
cd $HOME/_dev/_build

git clone https://github.com/crosstool-ng/crosstool-ng
cd crosstool-ng

# check out an older state, but they are not always error-free
#git checkout master # can have errors
git tag -l # list tags
git checkout tags/crosstool-ng-1.23.0 # choose last tag that works for you

./bootstrap

mkdir -p $HOME/_dev/_bin/ct-ng
./configure --prefix=$HOME/_dev/_bin/ct-ng

make
make install
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/_dev/_bin/ct-ng/bin" # if you want to use ct-ng in current shell

cd $HOME
rm -rf $HOME/_dev/_build
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I cound solve the issue myself: I had to un-check the Linaro compiler options and resort to the plain gcc. Additionally, I couldn't start the config & build process from my home directory as the config tool would store everything in a file named `.config`, but there is already a directory named .config.